# How to raise exceptions in Django view based in ORM exceptions

Tags: python, json, django, orm, model

Instead of doing, for example this:

views.py:

```
my_noob_way(request):
    object = Object.objects.filter(name=request.POST.get('name', None))
    if not object:
        Object.objects.create(name=request.POST.get('name', None))
        data = {'success': True, 'message': 'Object successfully created.'}
    else:
        data = {'success': False, 'message': 'Object already exists.'}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Instead of doing this, I want to avoid the `filter` line (extra garbage query) and just performing a `create` inside a `try` and catch the possible duplication exception with `except`. How can I make this?
I don't know what to put after `except:` (Too broad exception clause).

Comment: This is one if the reasons why you should use a `ModelForm` :)

Comment: I have a regular `Form` which I'm using for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

```
my_noob_way(request):
    object, created = Object.object.get_or_create(name=request.POST.get('name', None))
    message = 'Object successfully created.' if created else 'Object already exists.'
    return JsonResponse({'success': created, 'message': message})
```